# Control algorithm stops working after 5 min 30 sec on F28335

Tags: simulink

[image]I want to generate A sin(Wt) with A and W as external signals. As shown in figure i have done that. Sample time for blocks is 50e-6. I am using this block in inverter control algorithm. After downloading code on F28335 controller, it stops controlling after 5 min 30 sec. p.s. if i use inbuilt sine source block, it works fine. But, i want A and W configurable from external signals.

[image: Circuit Diagram]

Comment: Sorry, the image is not viewable in that forum. Could you upload it here?

Comment: It's possibly (probably?) related to saturation of the counter that is used to implement the code for the Digital Clock.  However without knowing what datatype is used on the F28335 it's hard to tell.  The inbuilt block doesn't use a counter which would explain why it works.

Comment: Phil, thanks for such a valuable input.
F28335 has 32-bit CPU.
I was using default data types of each block.
Now, i changed it to Fixdt(1,32,16).(all).
Can you give any other solution to get configurable(A and W) sine wave?

Comment: Phil, with Fixdt also problem not solved.

Comment: Alfabravo, Can you see image here?

Comment: @phil, can we give amplitude and frequency parameters of inbuilt sine source block via external signals?

Comment: If you make them MATLAB variables and define those variables as being Tunable, then yes, they will appear in the parameters structure of the code, and hence can be tuned.

Comment: @phil thanks
I used inbuilt sine block with A,W as workspace variable.
Q)i want to give that A and W value by SCI block of F28335.
How to do that?

Comment: simplified question
Q)Can i tune MATLAB workspace variable from SCI interface of F28335?

Comment: I have attached related image, what i want to do.

Comment: If A and W are being supplied as signals (from other blocks like this) then you do not have the option of using them in the built-in Sine Block.

Comment: @phil then is there any other alternative? mentioned problem still exist, though i tried changing many things.